# Custom Post Type UI query not showing every post

Tags: wordpress

I want to display all posts with the *Projekty wnętrz* category. Im using this query to achieve this, but it shows only few of posts (I added 8 and it shows only 6. I want to show always every post).

I have this problem with every category and it always shows only part of posts.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Realizacje'); ?>
            <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
            <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            $num = $loop->post_count; 
            $cat_id = get_cat_ID( 'Projekty wnętrz' );
            if (has_category( $cat_id )) {
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="realisation">
                        <!--   <div class="gallery">
                     <?php 
                     $images = get_field('galeria');
                    $size = 'medium'; 
                    if( $images ): ?>
                        <div id="lightgallery<?php echo $count; ?>">
                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                            <div class="gal">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                        </div> -->
                    <div class="galeria">
                        <div class="lightg" id="lightgallery<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                                    <div class="relative-box"><img class="first_image"src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
                                        <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </div></div>
                                    <div class="gallery-title"><h5 class="gallery-t"><?php the_title(); ?></h5></div>
                                </a>
                                <?php 
                                $count=$count+1;
                                $images = get_field('galeria');
                                $size = 'large'; 
                                if( $images ): ?>
                                    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></a> 
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>


                    <?php else: ?>
                        <h5>Brak realizacji</h5>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below full code. I've tested and it's working fine.

```
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <?php $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'Realizacje',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'cat' => $cat_id //add category id if you want filter the post by category othrwise remove
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        $num = $loop->post_count; 
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="realisation">
                <div class="galeria">
                    <div class="lightg" id="lightgallery<?php echo $count; ?>">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                                <div class="relative-box"><img class="first_image"src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
                                    <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div></div>
                                <div class="gallery-title"><h5 class="gallery-t"><?php the_title(); ?></h5></div>
                            </a>
                            <?php 
                            $count=$count+1;
                            $images = get_field('galeria');
                            $size = 'large'; 
                            if( $images ): ?>
                                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></a> 
                                <?php endforeach; ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
         else: ?>
        <h5>Brak realizacji</h5>
        <?php endif;
         wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using any [pagination parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) so it's possible you're getting only 10-12 posts from query based on how many posts per page value is set on backend settings.

Then on top of that, you are using `has_category( $cat_id )` to exclude the post content, You should not do this and should pass the category ID/slug in [category parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters), You should not use the name, You must work with category ID or slug.

Since you need all the posts from the category then you need to set `posts_per_page` to `-1`, and `-1` will display all the posts with all the filters used in Query.

the code will look like this after applying the above changes:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'Realizacje',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat'            => 101, // You need to change 101 with the category ID that you want to use.
);
/**
 * Note: If you want to use category slug then you will
 * have to use the 'category_name' param instead of using
 * 'cat' param and have to use category slug, not the name.
 * If you have to use multiple categories then you'll have 
 * to use the 'category__in' param instead of using the 'cat' param
 * 'category__in' will accept an array of category ids.
 */
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```